# Create Private Zones using DNSControl

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to create private zones in DNSControl?

I was able to use create-domains command via cloudbuild.yaml to create a zone in Cloud DNS. But what if I do not want it to be a Publicly Hosted Zone?

Thanks

Comment: You can create public zones in Google Cloud DNS. However, for the world to recognize those settings, the DNS server must be authoritative for your domain. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server#Authoritative_name_server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Google side the zone type is defined by the "visibility" attribute, but there is no support described for that in the DNSControl documentation neither for the `dnscontrol` command line nor language reference.